# Consumer offset topics corrupted on one leader in kafka cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka

We have a 6 node kafka cluster and one node 4 we are facing issue with consumer offset topic ex:

[root@kafka012-broker-shared-server2 kafka_2.11-1.1.1]# bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic __consumer_offsets | grep -w "Leader: 4"

```
    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 4       Replicas: 1,3,5 Isr: 4

    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 4    Leader: 4       Replicas: 5,1,3 Isr: 4

    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 10   Leader: 4       Replicas: 5,1,6,2,3     Isr: 4

    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 12   Leader: 4       Replicas: 1,3,5,2       Isr: 4

    Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 16   Leader: 4       Replicas: 5,1,3,6       Isr: 4
```

even these partitions folder are unavailable on /var/broker/data path.  Kafka cluster is created on aws and uses EBS volumes. We have tried reassigning partitions to other nodes in cluster however it says assignment already done.

We are noticing following error :
Group coordinator kafka012-broker-shared-server2:9094 (id: 2147483643 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery – vamsi krishna 2 hours ago   Delete

Comment: What error messages do you get on broker 4?

Comment: Group coordinator kafka012-broker-shared-server2:9094 (id: 2147483643 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery